# Setting up Send only mail server

Tags: mail-server, postfix-mta

I am setting a mail server for one of my website for which I am using external ZOHO mail server. But for sending mails through the website I am using postfix mail server. Now the issue I am facing is when I send mail through my website to some other mail eg. tushar@gmail.com it send the mail with no issue but if I send mail to one of my own domain email e.g. care@example.com the mail is not received.

I have follows this tutorial to setup send the only postfix:   and followed SPF record and DKIM setup using [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-an-spf-record-to-prevent-spoofing-improve-e-mail-reliability) and [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-dkim-with-postfix-on-debian-wheezy%20tutorial).

Comment: Missed the setup link: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-postfix-as-a-send-only-smtp-server-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: Update my: mydestination = $myhostname,localhost.$mydomain, $mydomain   .is there something wrong with this config

Comment: my log is showing :  to=<care@example.com>, relay=local, delay=0.05, delays=0.04/0/0/0, dsn=5.1.1, status=bounced (unknown user: "care")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the problem by removing $myhostname variable from mydestination, which probably changed the way mail was sent. Earlier it was through local and now it is being sent through smtp